# How to set onClickListener for the textviews generated dynamically?

Tags: java, android, textview

Can anyone please guide me on how to setOnClickListener for the TextViews that are generated dynamically.
I have few buttons in my app.Now when a particular button is clicked than some specific text elements are retrieved from the database based on the the number of elements returned corresponding TextViews are generated in order to display the retrieved text elements.
Now the problem that i'm having is that i don't know how to set onClickListner for the dynamically generated TextViews.Following is the piece of code where i'm creating my TextViews.Please guide me on what should i do.thank you

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageButton1:
catagory = "General";
            IndependentDB genData = IndependentDB.getInstance();
            genData.open(this);
            ArrayList<TextHolder> genList = new ArrayList<TextHolder>();
            genList = genData.getAllTextFromGenT();
            genData.close();
            x = genList.size();
            String xstr = new StringBuilder().append(x).toString();
            System.out.println(xstr);
            mainText = new TextView[x];
            textLayout = new LinearLayout[x];
            llseperator = new LinearLayout[x];
            textLayoutContainer
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_navy_blue);
            if (!genList.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    TextHolder firstOne = genList.get(i);
                    String text = firstOne.getText();
                    mainText[i] = new TextView(this);
                    mainText[i].setId(i);
                    mainText[i].setText("Text");
                    mainText[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    mainText[i].setTextSize(25);
                    mainText[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    mainText[i].setText(text);
                    mainText[i].setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                    mainText[i].setClickable(true);
                    mainText[i].setOnClickListener(this);
                    llseperator[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
                    llseperator[i].setId(i);
                    llseperator[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    llseperator[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    llseperator[i]
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tv_seperator);

                    textLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
                    textLayout[i].setId(i);
                    textLayout[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textLayout[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    textLayout[i].addView(mainText[i]);
                    textLayoutContainer.addView(textLayout[i]);
                    textLayoutContainer.addView(llseperator[i]);
                }// End of for
                }// End of If
        break;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `onClick()` method in Activity class (implemented View.setOnClickListener) so I suggest you to create a new class which implements View.setOnClickListener interface to handle click of TextView.

Try,

```
class TextClick implements View.setOnClickListener {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     TextView tx=(TextView) view;
     ...
   }
}
```

and set click listener,

```
 TextClick click=new TextClick();
 for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    TextHolder firstOne = genList.get(i);
    String text = firstOne.getText();
    mainText[i] = new TextView(this);      
    mainText[i].setOnClickListener(click);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.Alright gonna try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For example. you have a List tvs to store your TextView Objects created by the db result. What you should do is like this:

```
for(int i =0;i<tvs.count;i++){
tvs.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
...
})
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.your answer is not complete anyways but i got what you are trying to say.Im not sure whether i need to use for loop or not and if i have to then where it can fit in the code.I already tried using for loop once but got no success.Also i'm directly adding my TextViews in LinearLayout without using ListViews.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same setting on click listeners regardless of if the view was dynamically generated.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dosomething();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.but how it will know which TextView user is clicking on? i tried doing the following already insed the for loop that i have:
    mainText[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dosomething();
        }
    });
but this was affecting all the textviews instead of specific one which is clicked